# How to pass multiple files with variable filenames to the paste command

Tags: bash, shell, command, paste

Usually when we wish to concatenate several files column wise and the filenames of the files are just consecutive increasing integers we can do the following:

```
#Imagine I have 10 files
paste {1..10} > out
```

However, I'm currently working on a script in which the ranges are variables, so I want to be able to do something like this

```
first=1
last=10
paste {"${first}".."${last}"} > out
```

This doesn't work as variables can't be correctly expanded within the curly braces. Is there an alternative syntax I can use to achieve the same result?

Comment: `eval paste {"${first}".."${last}"} > file` ? But `eval is dangerous, so read up about that. Good luck.

Comment: Are the filenames *just* numbers, or are they something more complex like `file{1..10}.txt` (or worse, `"$prefixvar"{1..10}."$ext"`)?

Comment: in my particular case the filenames are just numbers without anything else

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to use `eval`, you can use [seq(1)](https://linux.die.net/man/1/seq):

```
seq -s ' ' "$first" "$last"
```

Like so:

```
paste $(seq -s ' ' "$first" "$last") > out
```

Comment: I was able to use this idea for my script, thank you

Answer (score 1):

Once upon a time a needed a seq like function but a way faster, so i made this

```
# Create sequence like {0..X}
cnt () { printf -v N %$1s; N=(${N// / 1}); printf "${!N[*]}"; }

$ cnt 5
0 1 2 3 4
```

And if we modify it a bit

```
# Create sequence like {X..Y}
cnt () { printf -v N %$2s; N=(${N// / 1}); N=(${!N[@]}); printf "${N[*]:$1} ${#N[@]}"; }

$ cnt 7 11
7 8 9 10 11
```